# HTML5 Access Camera on Android device fails

Tags: android, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am trying to print the Camera Input to a Canvas Element in HTML5. On the desktop it works fine, but building it for Android devices with cordova, I cannot access the camera and I really don't know what I do wrong. I also tried it with Crosswalk, there I get no error, but the Camera isn't shown either. But i want to do it with Cordova, becuase i have to use some Cordova Plugins.

Here is my Code:

```
   navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

   navigator.getUserMedia(options, onSuccess, onFail);

var options = {
     audio: false,
     video: {
      mandatory: {
       maxWidth: window.innerWidth,
       maxHeight: window.innerHeight
      },
      optional: [{ facingMode: "user" }]
 }
}

var onFail = function(e) {
  alert('Failed to get camera');
};

var onSuccess = function(stream) {
    var video = document.getElementById('my-webcam');
    if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        console.log("videoWidth" + video.width);
    } else {
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = url.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    // Wait 1000 ms before starting the loop otherwise the videosize aren´t set, so the Canvas can´t get values from the video
    setTimeout(function(){
        setInterval(updateCanvas,30); //manipulating the canvas here
        // Make sure the canvas is the same size as the video
        var video = document.getElementById('my-webcam'); //invisible
        var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas'); //where the camera input should be shown
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight; //- $('#mainPage_ButtonPhoto').height();
    },1000);
};
```

But if I build this, I always get the onfail alert "Failed to get camera".

I figured out it is a "errorPermissionDeniedError". I build it with xdk. But with this android.json, or app manifest for building android it is still not working.

```
{
"prepare_queue": {
    "installed": [],
    "uninstalled": []
},
"config_munge": {
    "files": {}
},
"installed_plugins": {},
"dependent_plugins": {},
"permissions": {
  "audio-capture": {
    "description": "Required to capture audio using getUserMedia()",
      access: "readwrite"
  },
  "video-capture": {
    "description": "Required to capture video using getUserMedia()",
      access: "readwrite"
  }
}
}
```